# How to destroy an instance variable of one class within the controller of another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing the chapter exercises of Agile Web Development with Rails. It's a store with products which you can add to a cart.  A product inside a cart is called a LineItem.  You can delete individual line items inside the cart.  When the last line item is deleted I want the entire cart to be destroyed.  The code I have doesn't work:

**CartsController**

```
def destroy
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.destroy
  session[:cart_id] = nil

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to store_path }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

**LineItemsController**

```
def destroy
  @cart = current_cart
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  quantity = @line_item.quantity

  if quantity > 1
    quantity -= 1
    @line_item.update_attribute(:quantity, quantity)
  else
    @line_item.destroy
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      if @cart.line_items.empty?
        @cart.destroy
      else
        redirect_to @cart
      end
    }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

This produces the following error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template line_items/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/mike/Projects/depot/app/views"
```

When the cart is destroyed I want to end up at store_path.

thanks,
mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the addition (as a comment):

```
  if @cart.line_items.empty?
    @cart.destroy
    # redirect_to store_path
  else
```

Comment: Ok, thanx a lot @prusswan. That works. But I don't understand why the redirect inside Cart.destroy doesn't do anything?

Comment: because when you call @cart.destroy from line_item#destroy, it still defaults to the render logic in line_item#destroy (the view page for destroy action if nothing is specified), unless you specifically redirect away to the destroy_path or some other path